# Geoserver+GDAL+OSGEO4W ECW support

Tags: qgis, geoserver, gdal, osgeo4w, ecw

I am trying to install the GDAL plugin for Geoserver on machines which have windows 7 and 10.
both machines had a previously installed version of OSGeo4W.

I followed all the instructions in the [official Geoserver guide](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html),
 but it seems to be outdated as it recommends using gdal versions that work with Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables which my machines don't have (i have the minimal 2015 while the most recent version in the [downloads page](https://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/native/gdal/1.9.2/) is 2010).

After unziping the *.jar files to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder, making sure that the `GDAL_DATA` variable is defined properly and making sure that the new GDAL version i installed is first on the `PATH` 
  variable and added the `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` variable to link to the ECW and MrSID *.dll's i still can't see the ECW format when i try to open a new data store in Geoserver (Yes, after restarting), I also copied the GDAL *.dll files to `wrapper/lib` folder as suggested [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html#note-on-running-geoserver-as-a-service-on-windows).

Is there some step I am missing?
Is there a way for Geoserver to recognize OSGEO4W's GDAL version and extensions?
I want to keep using the OSGeo4W version of QGIS since it contains the filegdb write option which i can't get to work in the other installment of QGIS.

**UPDATE**
Tested other plugins which seem to be working well, also tested that `gdalinfo` is using the 1.9.2 version that Geoserver needs to use and that it has ECW format support.
Still not working.

Comment: GeoServer requires a specific version of GDAL which may not be the one installed by OSGeo4W

Comment: which is why i pointed it to the version the guide instructed me to install and placed that version first on the path

Comment: @IanTurton still doesn't work after removing all other GDAL versions from path and making sure that version 1.9.2 is used and ECW is recognized format with `gdalinfo`